# Making phone call in windows phone 8.1 in a single tap

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, phone-call, dialing

I'm writing an emergency app and so I need to allow the user to make phone call in a single tap. All the articles I've been reading so far allows phone call in 2 taps. Is there a way to do that in only one tap?